# When seeding a RPNG with a slightly different seed, will be random numbers generated generally be offset or widely different?

Tags: random

I understand that this likely has to do with implementation. But in general, when seeding a RPNG with two slightly different seeds, will the random numbers generated generally be offset or widely different?

I am interested in the C library `random()` in particular.

I wonder if the random numbers that will be generated with the seeds `srandom(1345)` and `srandom(1346)` will be as widely different as the random numbers generated with the seeds `srandom(456)` and `srandom(234234132)`.

Comment: Why are you asking us?  Run the RNG with the seeds in your question and look at the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in James Freeman-Harris in 'The Statistics of Random Numbers' from 'AI Programming Wisdom 2', the [specification for random](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/BSD-Random.html#BSD-Random) is pretty loose, which allows for varying and inconsistent implementations. While I've never personally observed a correlation of similarities between seeds & output from off the shelf PRNGs, there's nothing in the spec to disallow it.

Furthermore, coming up with good, quantitative definitions for 'widely different' PRNG output can be challenging. How different is different? How big do your samples need to be?